# How can I switch the active window using Java?

Tags: java, ui-automation

Is there a Java library which facilitates good GUI automation tools under Windows? Specifically, something which can switch active windows like [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com) can.

I tried [SikuliX](http://sikulix.com), but with the exception of the image recognition tools, the library doesn't work very well. For example, when I try to switch to OneNote with `App.switchto("OneNote")` or `App.switchto("OneNote.exe")`, it often doesn't work.

The error log indicates that SikiliX confuses OneNote with another process with a similar name.

```
ONENOTE.EXE
[log] App.focus:  [9148:ONENOTEM.EXE]
```

Is there a better way to switch between active windows using Java?

Comment: I've done this one of two ways -- 1) via JNA, not too hard, or 2) Run AutoHotKey or (my preference) AutoIt in a process and have them communicate via sockets and streams, and this isn't too hard either.

Comment: I've never tried this using OLE/COM or DDE, but I imagine that by using the right libraries, it can be done this way too.

Comment: And thank you for the sikuli information. That's a tool that I've never heard of and could make some use of.

Comment: You could also try and make use of `autohotkey.dll` as shown in [this tutorial](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/108192-using-autohotkeydll-with-java/).